# Disable installation of my Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to prevent users from installing my facebook application to their pages, using the link below?

https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=API_KEY&pages

Note: I do not want to disable my application, I just want to disable new installations.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to achieve this is to parse the `signed_request` and compare the page information to a list of page ids you have authorised to use the app.

A *very* simple implementation would be along the lines of

```
<?php

$app_secret = 'APPSECRET';

$signed_request = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], $app_secret);

$page_whitelist = array(PAGEID1, PAGEID2);

if (in_array($signed_request['page']['id'], $page_whitelist)) {
    // do stuff
} else {
   // output some error message
}
```

https://gist.github.com/4157347

Comment: Yes I already know this way using page id records. But according to the link that I posted, I can not control who installs my app, when the action is triggered within facebook. There must be a way to disable new installations using the link posted.